# How to sort numbers that are in varchar type under GROUP BY GROUPING SETS in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column called UPC (varchar type) that only contain numbers.
I also have a GROUP BY GROUPING SETS on UPC.

Currently, it's sorted as varchar, which result the numbers not sorted from smallest to largest.

```
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS(([UPC]),())
```

[image]

If I use convert the UPC from varchar to bigint, the numbers will be sorted alphabetically but then my last row generated from GROUPING SETS will move from last to first.

```
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS(([UPC]),())       
ORDER BY convert(bigint, UPC)
```

[image]

Is there a way to make my "grand total" move to the last row and still have my numbers sorted alphabetically?
I'm guessing i might need to use GROUPING_ID?

Comment: You are on a wrong way. You need to help server, do not force it. If you have ETL package you will have solution to this voodoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customize your order by clause as in the example below:

```
Order by case when isnumeric(UPC) = 1 then convert(bigint, UPC) else 9999999999 end
```

the number 9999999999 represents the maximum number you may have

Comment: Would using grouping_id be faster for SQL Server to run?
i also got a suggestion like this: ORDER BY CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID((UPC)) = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,convert(bigint, UPC)